# Slide panel example in ipad /IOS using titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I saw a panel with is made in native app of IOS/iPad .Now I am looking same example in titanium .On button click panel is open ,and there is lot of button on panel user can move or change view on clicking the buttons .Can Is it possible in titanium

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about slider menu?

Comment: yes ..in IPAD you saw that..

Answer (score 0):

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-create-a-sliding-menu-for-ios/

IPAD and iphone works in the same manner so this solution would give you results for both

Thanks